# how I can MAKE CHART LINE FOR THE AVERAGE IN MY CHART ? reporting birt

Tags: report, reporting, birt

I  get  a graph from a data set, how can I  make an average like line again in this chart without to creat another data set
can I merge two chart?

Comment: Stack Exchange is not the place to ask for training, it is the place to ask for assistance with a problem.  If you have a specific issue that you can't solve ask it.

Comment: yeh i know , the probleme is ,  can i make an average like line again in chart without to creat another data set , can I merge two chart ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add marker lines on Yaxis or Xaxis, and set values dynamically by script.
Compute the average value in a birt table aggregation before the chart, set it in a persistent global variable and retrieve it in chart script handler "beforeDrawMarkerLine".

For example,"warning lines" of [this chart](http://www.visioneo.org/report-parameters?birt_viewType=chart&birt_displayedCharts=scatter) are set by script using average and standard deviation.

[image: BIRT scattered chart with dynamic marker lines]